# Showing Users based on current users Data in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created an extra field Date of Birth in the user fields.
Now how can I show all the users with the same birth date having the logged in users birth date.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a view of users with a contextual filter for the birthday field.  Set the filter to provide a default value in php code.  Then in the filter's PHP box, use the global $user object to fetch and return the current user's birthday.  Then to exclude the current user from the results, add a filter for user:current, and click the "no" option.

Comment: sorry but I don't have time to do this for you.